# Python Increasing counter by 1 every time something is written to a file

Tags: python, scripting

What I'm trying to do is every time the file 'TCPStreamPayload' is written to I want a counter that increases every time that information is appended to the file.

For example I have:

```
payloadRecon = open('TCPStreamPayload.txt','a')

segmentCount = 0

--my script here--
```

then at the bottom

```
if payloadRecon.write:
    segmentCount +=1
payloadRecon.write('####TCP PAYLOAD STREAM RECONSTRUCTION. Segment ' + str(segmentCount) + '######' '\n\n\n\n').
```

Basically, everytime I write to this file using my script I want the segment number to increase by 1.

Comment: Is your question really, how can I remember the last value of `segmentCount` between invocations of my script? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Couldn't you just call `payloadRecon.write` and then after `segmentCount += 1`? You could put a `try` around the write if you're worried that it won't work. What is the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should write a wrapper class and use that instead of a plain `file`:

```
class CountingWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.segment_count = 0
        self.f = open(*args, **kwargs)
    def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.segment_count += 1
        return self.f.write(*args, **kwargs)

payloadRecon = CountingWrapper('TCPStreamPayload.txt', 'a')
payloadRecon.write('dsfsd')
assert payloadRecon.count == 1
```

Alternatively, if you're just trying to wrap up the three lines of code so you don't have to keep repeating yourself, you can just write a wrapper function:

```
segmentCount = 0
def payload_write(f, *args, **kwargs):
    global segmentCount
    segmentCount += 1
    return f.write(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now, you just need this one-liner to count and write:

```
payload_write(payloadRecon, '####TCP PAYLOAD STREAM RECONSTRUCTION. Segment ' + str(segmentCount) + '######' '\n\n\n\n')
assert segmentCount == 1
```

The class is more flexible, if you need to wrap multiple methods. But you obviously need to delegate any other methods you care about. Of course you could do the delegation dynamically, via `__getattr__`. Or you could use inheritance. (But keep in mind that in 3.x, the class is not `file`, but one of the classes in the `io` package, and you're not supposed to create either `file` or `io.whatever` by constructor anyway, but by `open`, so you'll still need to write a wrapper factory function to replace `open`. The good news is, that means you don't need to handle `__new__`, just `__init__`.)

In 3.x, you could even monkeypatch the instance (but this won't work in 2.x, where `file.write` is read-only):

```
payloadRecon = open('TCPStreamPayload.txt', 'a')
segmentCount = 0
write_original = payloadRecon.write
def write_and_count(self, *args, **kwargs):
    global segmentCount
    segmentCount += 1
    write_original(self, *args, **kwargs)
payloadRecon.write = write_and_count
```

But really, keeping things explicit is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :D Appreciate it!

Comment: AttributeError: 'file' object attribute 'write' is read-only
on py2, in py3 it is fine though.

Comment: @EricRoper: The whole point of `*args` is that it takes the `args` tuple and splits it back up into a bunch of separate args. This is how you do generic perfect forwarding of arguments in Python. For example, `def wrap_open(*args, *kwargs): return open(*args, **kwargs)`, then `f = wrap_open("bar.txt", "a")`, then examine `f`.

Comment: @möter: Ah, didn't realize that. Well, that's not the best way to do it anyway, but I'll edit the answer to make that distinction.